# Why doesn't svn merge do anything?

Tags: svn

I am trying to understand in detail how `svn merge` works.

I have a file `test` committed in two revisions:

in revision 230553, it has one character `/` (and the newline)

in revision 235554, it has one character `$` (and the newline):

```
svn diff -r 230553:230554 test
Index: test
===================================================================
--- test        (revision 230553)
+++ test        (revision 230554)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-/
+$
```

The current local version, is changed back to `/`.  Now, I expect that if do this:

```
svn merge test@230553 test@230554
```

the local copy will change to `$`.  But no, nothing happens, the command succeeds, does not complain, but the file `test` is not even touched.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: Perhaps you want to try something more like `svn merge -r230553:230554 branchURL`  (where branchURL is the URL of the SVN branch to merge in the changes from)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It is the same thing as I am doing. Does not work, in the same way. Also, my question was "why", not "how". There is some fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Have you tried with the option `--ignore-ancestry` ? or to invert the revisions in the command line ?

Comment: @LaurentH. yes `--ignore-ancestry` worked.  Thank you!  I will study this option and figure out why it is needed in this case.  Please make it an answer and I will accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, when you run the command line `svn merge test@230553 test@230554`, you are trying to apply to your local file the modifications that you have already done on revision 230554. Your problem here is that, by default, SVN does not perform the merge if the same modifications had already been done on the ancestry. So you have to ask it in a more kindly manner with the option `--ignore-ancestry`. This line should work:

```
svn merge test@230553 test@230554 --ignore-ancestry
```